# How to add a layer which is implemented by TensorFlow into a PyTorch neural model?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, customization

I’d like to add some layer into a Pytorch based neural model. Basically I am trying to combine to codes together.

But I notice that the layer I want to add is the implemented by Tensorflow. I’d like to know if there is an easy way to integrate a TensorFlow layer into a Pytorch neural model… ?

The error is shown as:

module ‘torch.nn’ has no attribute ‘tensorflow_layer’

Comment: What kind of layer you are talking about? You can always use PyTorch to create a same layer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, I understand that PyTorch can implement the same simple layer. But the layer I am going to add is a complex layer, which is dynamically changing during the training. So it is really complex to rewrite the whole code by using Pytorch...

Comment: Would you mind to show us the architecture?